# Maintaining spaces at the beginning of lines when wrapping

Tags: javascript, html, css

HTML wraps so that each new line begins with text.

For example, given the following `div`, each line after the first *begins* with the letter O, regardless of screen width:

```css
div {
  font-size: 30pt;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

```html
<div>
              O O            O   O        O  O OO                   O          O O             O O              O          O                               O
</div>
```

Is there an HTML/CSS way to wrap the `div` so that new lines can begin with *spaces*?

The best I can come up with is using JavaScript to split the `div` into one-character wide spans, with a left float, and spaces changed to non-breaking spaces:

```
div, span {
  font-size: 30pt;
  float: left;
}

var div= document.getElementsByTagName('div');
var data= div[0].innerHTML.split('');
var s = '';
for(var i = 0 ; i < data.length ; i++) {
  s+= '<span>'+data[i].replace(' ','&nbsp;')+'</span>';
}
div[0].innerHTML= s;
```

However, that creates a lot of DOM elements.

### Fiddle

Comment: It works as you are wanting on Chrome

Comment: @Le-roy, true, but I was wondering if there was an HTML/CSS solution to this.

Comment: ... or a JavaScript solution that didn't require so many DOM elements.

Comment: I don't think there's a pure CSS way to achieve this